# While Running in the app im getting this error. Can anyone help and tell me what this error is?

Tags: flutter, flutter-android, targetsdkversion

```
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7onJ6.png)

Though the app is running but at times it takes the token value a null in the emulator and doesn't run / function properly win actual android device but works fine on IOS and IOs devices.

I tried changing the sdkVersions manually but getting other errors as minsdkversion is higher or paticular plugin is not suitable with this sdkversion.

Below details might be usefull for everyone to help me.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion 

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.something"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

***Thank you.***

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't worry: it's not an error.
It's a warning related to your **Android Build Tools** version. If you want to fix it try reinstalling your Android SDK first with the latest version available.

If that doesn't work your best option is to download the latest [Gradle](https://gradle.org/install/) release.

[Fix guide](https://flutter-examples.com/flutter-project-build-warning-mapping-new-ns-error-solution/)

Comment: this helps to clear the mapping error but the issue is, The app dosent function properly in android but works fine without error in ios. Need help with that bro.